# Regular Expression Jmeter return null

Tags: html, regex, jmeter

I try this script on my the jmeter regex tester :

```
<a(?:[^>]id\=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lnkHistoryTaxFileName.*?doPostBack\(&#39;(.*?)\&\#39[^>]*)?>(.*?)<\/a>\r\n.*?\r\n.*?\r\n.*?<span\sid\=\"ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus.*?\".*?>Opened<\/span>
```

tested on this html code :

```
<a id="ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lnkHistoryTaxFileName_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ucManageTaxFilesGridControl$gridAccountHistory$ctl04$lnkHistoryTaxFileName&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="font-family:Tahoma;font-size:0.8em;font-weight:bold;">TaxFile1</a>

              </td><td>                                                
                <span id="ucManageTaxFilesGridControl_gridAccountHistory_lblHistoryStatus_2" style="color:Black;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:0.8em;">Opened</span>
```

it returns me the expected result  but returns null values during the execution of my http sampler.

do i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a better idea to use a html parser to get the value of the attributes you want to check. Then you can apply a regex on that attribute value. Those regexes would probably be a lot easier to write.

Answer (score 0):

rednaw is right, it isn't a good idea to parse HTML with regular expressions. JMeter provides powerful [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0)

something like `//a[contains(@id,'ManageTaxFilesGridControl')]/@href` should return postback url .

There is a nice [XPath tutorial at w3schools](http://w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) if you're not comfortable with it. In general, XPath is much easier than RegEx.